# mail chimp integration in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mailchimp

I am googling since last two weeks but found no idea about how to integrate mail chimp in mvc3 . Does know about this, any example or link?

Answer (score 2):

Mailchimp [provide an API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/rtfm/) (oh, yeah, I like how they named the resource in this url `/api/rtfm/` - hilarious) that works over the HTTP protocol. And here are some [other APIs](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/). So I would recommend you first reading their documentation.

Then you could use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to consume this API from your application.

Comment: i am building a survey website the thing i want that user can send his survey link to his contact using mail chimp . Can i do this by webclient ?

Comment: @AhsanAshfaq, did you read the MailChimp documentation? They must have covered this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It depends technology framework you are trying to integrate the MailChimp API here.
As when  it comes to MVC framework, I think you should go through this excellent [github repository.](https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-php-examples)
  It has a simple example given for reference along with the instructions and necessary documentation.

As mentioned over there edit `Controller/AppController.php`. Inside the single quotes, paste your [MailChimp API Key](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/where-can-i-find-my-api-key) into

```
$this->mc = new Mailchimp(''); //your api key here
```

Also refer the [API documentation](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#php).